# Searching for Hebrew cantillation marks in Hebrew

Tags: javascript, unicode, hebrew

I am trying to search for the Hebrew cantillation mark [etnachta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgHhA.jpg), u-0591 in unicode via JavaScript. I put in the following code, and even though it's there, my search comes up false. Is there anything I can do differently to make it work?

```js
const verse = ['וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָ֜ם אֶל־ל֗וֹט אַל־נָ֨א תְהִ֤י מְרִיבָה֙ בֵּינִ֣י וּבֵינֶ֔יךָ וּבֵ֥ין רֹעַ֖י וּבֵ֣ין רֹעֶ֑יךָ כִּֽי־אֲנָשִׁ֥ים אַחִ֖ים אֲנָֽחְנוּ'];
if (verse.includes(/^\u0591/)) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

You can see where the symbol is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwkJa.png) (Genesis 13:8).

I even used [JavaScript escapes](https://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%99%D6%BC%D6%B9%D6%A8%D7%90%D7%9E%D6%B6%D7%A8%20%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B8%D6%9C%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%9C%D6%97%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%98%20%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%9C%D6%BE%D7%A0%D6%B8%D6%A8%D7%90%20%D7%AA%D6%B0%D7%94%D6%B4%D6%A4%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A8%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%91%D6%B8%D7%94%D6%99%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B4%D6%A3%D7%99%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%91%D6%B5%D7%99%D7%A0%D6%B6%D6%94%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%91%D6%B5%D6%A5%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A8%D6%B9%D7%A2%D6%B7%D6%96%D7%99%20%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%91%D6%B5%D6%A3%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A8%D6%B9%D7%A2%D6%B6%D6%91%D7%99%D7%9A%D6%B8%20%D7%9B%D6%BC%D6%B4%D6%BD%D7%99%D6%BE%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%A0%D6%B8%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B4%D6%A5%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%97%D6%B4%D6%96%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%A0%D6%B8%D6%BD%D7%97%D6%B0%D7%A0%D7%95%D6%BC%D7%83) and it came up with:

> '\u05D5\u05B7\u05D9\u05BC\u05B9\u05A8\u05D0\u05DE\u05B6\u05E8 \u05D0\u05B7\u05D1\u05B0\u05E8\u05B8\u059C\u05DD \u05D0\u05B6\u05DC\u05BE\u05DC\u0597\u05D5\u05B9\u05D8 \u05D0\u05B7\u05DC\u05BE\u05E0\u05B8\u05A8\u05D0 \u05EA\u05B0\u05D4\u05B4\u05A4\u05D9 \u05DE\u05B0\u05E8\u05B4\u05D9\u05D1\u05B8\u05D4\u0599 \u05D1\u05BC\u05B5\u05D9\u05E0\u05B4\u05A3\u05D9 \u05D5\u05BC\u05D1\u05B5\u05D9\u05E0\u05B6\u0594\u05D9\u05DA\u05B8 \u05D5\u05BC\u05D1\u05B5\u05A5\u05D9\u05DF \u05E8\u05B9\u05E2\u05B7\u0596\u05D9 \u05D5\u05BC\u05D1\u05B5\u05A3\u05D9\u05DF \u05E8\u05B9\u05E2\u05B6\u0591\u05D9\u05DA\u05B8 \u05DB\u05BC\u05B4\u05BD\u05D9\u05BE\u05D0\u05B2\u05E0\u05B8\u05E9\u05C1\u05B4\u05A5\u05D9\u05DD \u05D0\u05B7\u05D7\u05B4\u0596\u05D9\u05DD \u05D0\u05B2\u05E0\u05B8\u05BD\u05D7\u05B0\u05E0\u05D5\u05BC\u05C3'

Comment: `console.log(['ab'].includes(/a/));` doesn't work either. [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) doesn't seem to search for substrings, let alone accept regular expressions.

Comment: Your `include` doesn't search in the string, but rather in the array elements. You need `verse[0].includes('\u0591')` instead. Or simply `'וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָ֜ם אֶל־ל֗וֹט אַל־נָ֨א תְהִ֤י מְרִיבָה֙ בֵּינִ֣י וּבֵינֶ֔יךָ וּבֵ֥ין רֹעַ֖י וּבֵ֣ין רֹעֶ֑יךָ כִּֽי־אֲנָשִׁ֥ים אַחִ֖ים אֲנָֽחְנוּ'.includes('\u0591')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem has nothing to do with hebrew or unicode chars, but to the way you search.

It can be that you are trying to find a regex match in a **array** of strings. If that is the case, then the search is not correct. To search against a regex inside an array, `Array.include` is no your friend. You will need to iterate with something like `Array.findIndex()` or  `Array.filter()`

```
const verse = ['וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָ֜ם אֶל־ל֗וֹט אַחִ֖ים אֲנָֽחְנוּ'];  
if (verse.findIndex( v => v.search(/^\u0591/) ) != -1) ...
```

If you want instead regex match against a simple string, you will need to remove your `[]` around your string and use `String.search()`

```
 const verse = 'וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָ֜ם אֶל־ל֗וֹט אַחִ֖ים אֲנָֽחְנוּ';  
 if (verse.search(/^\u0591/)) ...
```

And finally if you want to just find `\u0591` inside the string, you may simply use `String.includes()`

```
const verse = 'וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אַבְרָ֜ם אֶל־ל֗וֹט אַחִ֖ים אֲנָֽחְנוּ';  
if (verse.includes('\u0591')) ...
```